# When does Android check Min-sdk?

Tags: android, exception

My application is targeted for API 8 (Froyo) minimum, however I'm getting a message in the Android Market that says "This report was sent in by a pre-Froyo client, which did not include a stack trace."

When does Android check that the Min-sdk is greater than or equal to the API version on the phone.  Is it at runtime or market download time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app's `minSdkVersion` is filtered by the Market **and** the phone, *however* there are a few ROMs out there that disable this filtering at the phone-level. If you're seeing a report from a phone that is below your `minSdkVersion` it usually means the user installed the app directly, not from the market, and their phone tried to run it even though the SDK version wasn't usable by the device. This would result in a bug report being posted to the Market, but the Market app doesn't ask the device how it got the app in the first place.

You'll see this once in a really long while--it's nothing to be alarmed about.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* it filters in the market. Perhaps somebody got ahold of your APK and distributed it to a pre-Froyo phone? Just a guess.

edit - taken from the ref http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html: An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.

Perhaps you have confused minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion?

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> is whats declared in the manifest

Comment: Interesting, is this message from a bug report in the market? If so, it appears that there is some contradiction between the reference and the implementation.